# How to print all the properties of a function-object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

The target is to print all properties of a function-object.

Could it be implemented via overwriting the toString-method of the prototype-property (which itself is a `function`) in the Function-object (is that even the right spot?)?

I know that e.g. following is possible, to modify the single properties with the utility `Object.defineProperty` which can be used to change properties attributes like e.g. `enumerable`. After that it would occur in a loop.

```
Object.defineProperty(Function, 'length', {
  enumerable: true
});

Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Function, 'length')
{value: 1, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}

for (let a in Function){
    console.log(a);
}
```

I would like to see the scopes respectively closures that exist in the [[Scopes]]-property, but somehow I think exactly this is not meant to be possible.

Comment: 1/2 ... *"The target is to print all properties of a function-object ..."* ... `Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Function.prototype)).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log([key, JSON.stringify(value)].join(': ')));` ... *"Is there a possibility to modify the prototype-property"* ... the OP just did demonstrate how one would achieve that (then with `Function.prototype` instead of just `Function`) ...

Comment: 2/2 ... *"I would like to see the scopes respectively closures that exist"* ... one can not retrieve/access such information from the outside. One also can not access *scope*; one might, within a controlled environment, be able of accessing some data which does exist within *scope* (regardless of whether being preserved scope) ... There were three questions with the latter one not being related to the chosen topic. What is the OP's real goal?

Comment: OP's real goal rephrased: By printing out the properties of the function `Function`, which is a constructor function according to convention written with capital the `F`, viewing the [[Scopes]]-property and better understanding the handling of scopes by making it tangible how the variables are being managed that are closed over by a closure.